# How to set contact as favourite through coding?

Tags: android

I need to toggle existing android contacts to favourite. I have a toggle button which is suppose to set/unset current contact as favourite.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the People.STARRED value:

```
// 1 = the new contact is added to favorites
// 0 = the new contact is not added to favorites
values.put(People.STARRED, 1);
```

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for details.

Comment: can you please explain this in detail? how did you add contact as favourite?